# Как из одного массива собрать другой массив php

Tags: php, php7

Имеется массив вида

```html
Array
(
    [0] => 2022-5
    [1] => 2022-6
    [2] => 2022-7
)
```

Каким способом можно из него сделать массив следущего вида

```html
Array
(
    [2022] => 
        Array (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
            )
)
```

Спасибо гениальному гению :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Исходный массив
$src = Array("2022-5","2022-6","2022-7");

//результирующий массив
$new_array = Array();

//пройтись по всем элементам исходного массива
foreach ($src as $key=>$val) {
    // разделить xxxx-xx, на две части. используя в кач. разделителя -
    // https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php
    $v = explode("-",$val); // $v[0] - год, $v[1] = месяц

    //только уникальные месяцы? Можно удалить, если не нужно
    if (!in_array($v[1], $new_array[$v[0]]) ) { 

        // для добавления нового элемента в массив, можно использовать
        // []; например $x[] = 10 - добавит в конец массива $x 10
        $new_array[$v[0]][] = $v[1]; // добавление в новый массив
    }
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: К сожалению данный код ругается Notice
Notice
: Undefined offset: 2022 in

Warning
: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in

Comment: решение супер, заменил "!in_array($v[1], $new_array[$v[0]]" на "!in_array($v[1], array($v[0])" и все работает)

Comment: да, потому что первый раз, нет массива года с месяцами. Можно добавить if (!isset($new_array[$v[0]])) $new_array[$v[0]] = array(); но это только бы усложнило и запутало. Можно еще поставить @ в начале той строки где ругается, это уберет warning. Ругаться перестало, потому что вы сделали array($v[0]) - это всегда массив из года(!), и вы проверяете в нем месяц )) Это всегда отрицательный результат, и будут дубли месяцев.

Answer (score -1):

Используйте многомерные массивы. В массив можно вложить другой массив.

$array[2022]= array2;

Comment: чуть не так, мне нужно чтобы автоматически создавался такой массив с учетом всех последующих годов 2023...2024...

Comment: не совсем понятно, откуда беруться данные. Напишите подробнее. что есть на входу и что должно быть на выходе.